# How to convert a polynomial user input into python readable form

Tags: python, function, user-input, numerical-methods, polynomials

I have the following input:

[image]

and I want to convert it into python readable form like this `'x**2 + 2*x + 2'` so that I can use it as an input to other functions. I have:

```
def func_parse(func):
    return func.replace("^","**")
```

but this will only resolve the power part. I also want to add '*' in between '2x' to conform with the python syntax.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have a read on [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show your efforts in code, describe what you are struggling with. This is not *write me a code* forum

Comment: This is a task, not a question. What have you tried to implement [one of the approaches you can find here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+equation+python) and elsewhere to parse inputs of mathematical equations? Which specific problem during this implementation did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (
    parse_expr, stringify_expr, standard_transformations,
    implicit_multiplication_application, convert_xor
)

transformations = (standard_transformations 
                   + (implicit_multiplication_application, convert_xor))

f = 'x^2 + 2x + 3'
expr = parse_expr(f, transformations=transformations)
```

Output:

```
>>> str(expr)
'x**2 + 2*x + 3'
```

**Update**

> Evaluate the polynomial output with an integer value, let's say (x =2).

```
>>> expr.evalf(subs=dict(x=2))
11.0000000000000
```

Comment: can you please help me with evaluating the polynomial output with an integer value, let's say (x =2). As eval() is a dangerous way to evaluate it

Comment: @Am_ai. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: It helps !! Thank you ...I've upvoted your solution :)